# How to send an E-Mail with PHP?

Tags: php, html, email

I'm not really familiar with PHP and I tried to implement a simple mail-script onto my page. But nothing seems to happen. The Server I'm on definitely supports PHP. Do I have to do anything else than just upload my files?

So I have my contact.php and in it there is just normal HTML-Code with a < ?php ?> Tag in the < head> section.

It goes like this:

```
<?php
    // Ausführen wenn Formular gesendet
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {

        // Sammeln der Formulardaten
        $an = "MYMAILADRESS@outlook.com";
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $betreff = $_POST['betreff'];
        $nachricht = $_POST['nachricht'];

        // Mailheader UTF-8 fähig machen
        $mail_header = 'From:' . $email . "\n";
        $mail_header .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

        // Nachrichtenlayout erstellen
        $message = "
            Name:       $name\n
            Email:      $email\n
            Nachricht:  $nachricht\n
        ";

        // Verschicken der Mail
        mail($an, $betreff, $message, $mail_header );
    };
?>
```

Of Course I changed "MYMAILADRESS" intentionally.
The HTML-form looks like this:

```
<form id="form" action="thank_you.html" method="post">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" /><br />
        <label for="email">E-Mail: *</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" /><br />
        <label for="betreff">Betreff:</label>
        <input id="betreff" name="betreff" type="text" /><br />
        <label for="nachricht">Nachricht: *</label>
        <textarea id="nachricht" name="nachricht"></textarea><br />
        <p class="fussnote">* kennzeichnet Pflichtfelder</p>
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Absenden" />
    </form>
```

If anybody could help me with this, it'd be great! :)

Comment: If the form action is going to thank_you.html - that won't run PHP code, unless you have specifically setup the webserver to do so - which you are very unlikely to have done so.

Answer (score 1):

The `action` of your form is pointing to a URL that is probably resolved by a `.html` file. Most web servers that support PHP are not configured to run `.html` files through the PHP processor. Use `.php` extension instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've supplied should work, but be warned that you are leaving yourself open to potential hacks.

PHP's `mail()` function makes no effort to sanitise the input it receives; it would be possible for your visitors to send a `from` address with line feeds, and add a kinds of additional mail headers (eg CC or BCC) in order to send spam from your site.

It's relatively easy to sanitise the input, but even then you're left with the `mail()` function not being very easy to use - you'll end up with lots of code for relatively little functionality.

For this reason, I would always recommend using a third party mailer library. There are several good ones available for PHP; my preferred choice is [phpMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer). Download this PHP script, include it as part of your site, and follow the instructions on how to send mail using it -- you'll find it's a lot easier to use than the `mail()` function, and you don't need to worry about hacking attacks because it does all the input sanitisation work for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out! But I still want to know, why this simple script isn't working... ;)

Answer (score -1):

This your problem,

> So I have my contact.php and in it there is just normal HTML-Code with a < ?php ?> Tag in the < head> section.

Move the PHP code (inc tags), into your HTML body tags.

Also, change your form action to your .php file.

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but no reaction whatsoever... :/

Comment: Add a simple _echo 'Test';_ before your mail() function.
Just so we can see you're getting that far.

Comment: Still nothing. But the server supports PHP, about that I'm sure... :/